# Multi-stage build cannot exclude files from .dockerignore

Tags: docker

When I tried to reduce the size of the image, I used the multi-stage builds. But there has a problem that it didn't exclude the files(.dockerignore mentioned files) from the 2nd image. There is the example below:

```
myfolder/      
node_modules/
.dockerignore 
.gitignore    
Dockerfile  
package.json  
index.js
yarn.lock
```

and Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

# Until now, node_modules folder has not existed.

RUN yarn

FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=0 /app .

# node_modules folder is copied to workdir...
```

Certainly, I could copy files and folders one by one. Is there any better solution?

Comment: Why do you use a multi-stage build in your example? As far as I can see, your image of the second build stage is exactly the same as the image of the first. In that case, you could only use the first build stage and remove all unnecessary files using `RUN rm -rf file`. Which files do you like to remove? What command do you like to run in the container?

Comment: @maiermic The original intent is reducing the image size. 

Unfortunately, using `RUN rm -rf file.` cannot move the previous layer out of the image.

Comment: @maiermic The files I like to remove was the dev dependenies(babel, eslint, etc). I have to compile the ES with babel before the node server start up, but I dont want to keep the babel packages in the image. In the first stage, using the `yarn install` or `npm install` to get all the dependenies and then do the code-building. In the final stage, I tried using the `npm install --production` but not work.

Comment: You say that you need the dev dependencies to build code, but you don't run a build command in your Dockerfile.

Comment: You are right that image size is not reduced if you use `RUN rm -rf file` after `RUN yarn`. I meant `RUN yarn && rm -rf file`. You might install all dependencies (including dev), build your app (I suppose `yarn run build`) remove all dependencies, install production dependencies from cache and delete cache files: `RUN yarn && yarn run build && rm -rf node_modules && yarn --production && yarn cache clean`

Comment: @maiermic Sorry for the late reply, and appreciate your reply. :) It lacked the build command because I wanted to make the question focused on doing the exclusion method with Docker. So far I have the workaround close to your solution which totally reduces the size of the docker image. But it makes us install all dependencies, not the cache layer, everytime we build the image. Finally, I separated it into 2 images to solve the problem, but not the multi-stage.

Comment: You have to install all dependencies every time you build your app, but `yarn --production` can at least use the cache of `yarn` run earlier. The goal was to reduce the size of the image. To speedup build-time you could store dependencies in an image layer, but this increases the image size. That is why you'd like to use another build-stage for your final image.

Comment: You wrote "I could copy files and folders one by one". Which files are generated in build stage that should be copied to production stage? Are there any (source) files on your host that should only be copied to build stage but not to production stage?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it, certainly, I don't need to pass any source files on the production stage. It seems like the correct answer is passing files and folders one by one, not depending on the ignore file.

Answer (score 2):

In the first stage, you don't see `node_modules/` because it's ignored by docker before sending files to the daemon but after `RUN yarn` you are building a new `node_modules/` which have then copied to the second stage, and because of `.dockerignore` can affect ONLY before starting to build the first one, and you see that in the final image